# Facebook PHP API date only event

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i create an event with the API and i don't specify a start and end time then facebook automatically adds a time of 10am start and 1am end. Why is it not possible to just add a date only event. When I login to facebook and i create an event there then the time is optional and there is no bogus times added in. Is there an option i am not including in the array that i pass though. Here is some sample code of my request

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => //key
        'secret' => //secret
    ));

    $facebook->setAccessToken(/*USER ACCESS TOKEN*/);

    try{
        $retObj = $facebook->api('/<USER ID>/events/create', 'POST', array(
            "name" => //title,
            "description" => //description,
            "start_time" => //date only eg. 2013-03-20,
            "end_time" => //date only eg. 2013-03-25
        ));

    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#events there is no `is_date_only` parameter.

Comment: Thats just something i added in frustration. Ill remove that from the sample code. The reason it got added was that when you request an event then that is part of the return result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create an event without specifying a `start_time`, so I don't know how you could have created the event. To create a **date-only** event, just do:

```
$retObj = $facebook->api('/<USER ID>/events/create', 'POST', array(
            "name" => "My event", //compulsory field
            "start_time" => "2013-03-19" //tomorrows's date
));
```

Comment: Hi Stephane, the code i posted was just sample code its not what i am using. Your method works only if you don't specify an end time. If you add an end time in date only format eg '2013-03-22' then it automatically adds times in.

Comment: Date-only events are only possible for _one_ day – if you just pass a date as start_time, then you get a date-only event. But events spanning multiple days can not be date-only events. So you have to add start/end time yourself (f.e. 00:00:00 for start, 23:59:59 for end).

Comment: That's such a stupid design. But theres nothing i can do i guess but to add the times in myself. Thanks for all the help guys. Stephane I am marking your answer as accepted. You did show some light at the end of the tunnel

Comment: oh, one more thing. i see when you add an event using facebook's interface it works without adding a time in for any fields. Wonder why they have it like this in the api.